# Как запустить Ubuntu c загрузочного диска на USB / Как вернуться в Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, usb, dual-boot

Буду благодарен за пошаговые инструкции:

1. Есть загрузочный диск на USB с образом Ubuntu. Как его запустить?
2. Как после запуска Ubuntu вернуться в Windows?

Comment: А вы на сайте Ubuntu инструкции читали или на каком-то форуме? Какая у вас ОС установлена сейчас на ПК? Вы хотите установить на новый (чистый ПК), или с другой ОС, я об этом. И с какой версией Ubuntu у вас диск?

Comment: 1. Нет, инструкции не читал. Создал bootable stick вот по этой инструкции: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1
2. Сейчас на ПК Windows 10
3. Я хочу запустить Ubuntu c USB диска, не трогая Windows, да с другой ОС.
4. Версия Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: Я просто так и не понял, у вас загрузочный USB не грузиться, так ?

Comment: "Прежде чем войти куда-то, подумай о том как ты оттуда выйдешь" (C). Я ещё не запускал загрузочный диск. Перед этим я хотел понять всю процедуру входа и выхода целиком. Ранее опыта с Ubuntu не имел.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Вопрос:*

> Есть загрузочный диск на USB с образом Ubuntu. Как его запустить?

*Ответ:*

**Необходимые условия:**

1. Подключение к сети интернет, т.к. во время установки будут загружены дополнительные пакеты программ, которые не поместились на установочный образ.
2. Диск или флешка с `iso-образом`

**Установка**

1. Вставьте диск в дисковод, либо флешку в порт и перезагрузите компьютер. После перезагрузки должно открыться на экране окно приветствия **Welcome**, где нужно выбрать язык:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда вы выберите язык, в окне приветствия будет предложено два варианта: **Запустить Ubuntu** и **Установить Ubuntu**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы выберите **Запустить Ubuntu**, то система будет загружена в `Live-режиме`, т.е. без установки на ж/диск компьютера и можно будет "пощупать" Ubuntu, а в дальнейшем перейти к установке. В случае с выбором **Установить Ubuntu**, вы перейдёте к непосредственной установке.

Предположим вы выбрали **Запустить Ubuntu**. Должен открыться рабочий стол Ubuntu:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После знакомства с Ubuntu, вы можете перейти к непосредственной установке.
 Двойной клик на значке на рабочем столе - **Установить Ubuntu**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если язык выбран вами правильно, нажмите копку **Продолжить**, чтобы перейти к следующему шагу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В шаге **Подготовка к установке Ubuntu**, активируйте оба пункта:
*Загрузить обновления при установке* и *Установить сторонне программное обеспечение, как на верхнем снимке* и *Продолжить*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В шаге Тип установки нужно выбрать один из трёх типов. У меня установлено несколько систем на жестком диске, у вас может быть одна, но суть от этого не меняется. Если вы не умеете разбивать жесткий диск на разделы, оставьте активированным первый пункт и установщик сам найдет место рядом с установленной системой, не причинив ей ни какого вреда.

Либо вы можете выбрать второй вариант, который предлагает *Стереть диск и установить Ubuntu*. В этом случае сотрётся всё что у вас есть на ж/диске и установится только Ubuntu.

И наконец третий вариант - Другой вариант, предлагает *создать и изменить разделы самостоятельно* для Ubuntu (для опытных пользователей).

Выбрав первый пункт **Установить Ubuntu** рядом с ними, нажмите **Продолжить**, после чего откроется следующий шаг, где будет предложено автоматическое разбиение пространства на ж/диске, но вы можете поместить курсор в центр, между двух разделов и двигать его, тем самым изменяя размеры разделов.
В случае выбора третьего варианта - Другой вариант, вы можете выбрать один из существующих разделов, двойной клик на строке с разделом и в открывшемся окне Изменить раздел, в параметре **Использовать** как выберите Журналируемая файловая система `Ext4`; поставьте флажок в параметре *Форматировать раздел*; Точка монтирования - корневой раздел / (правый слэш) и нажмите ОК, как на нижнем снимке :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того как вы определились с разделами, нажмите **Установить сейчас**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откроется окно с пояснениями о том что раздел будет отформатирован и пр. Если вы сомневаетесь или выбрали не тот раздел ж/диска, то есть возможность вернуться и переделать созданный раздел, либо переключиться на другой, нажав кнопку **Вернуться**.
Если всё правильно, нажмите *Продолжить*, чтобы перейти к следующему шагу.
Далее, в окне установки *Где вы находитесь?* введите в поле внизу окна название вашей местности, либо кликните на карте, для правильного отображения времени в системе и **Продолжить**.
Следующим шагом будет определение Раскладки клавиатуры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь вам предложено выбрать язык раскладки клавиатуры и Продолжить.

Откроется приветственное окно, демонстрирующее возможности Ubuntu, с которыми можно познакомиться до окончания установки.  Дождитесь окончания установки.

Когда установка закончится, откроется последнее окно установщика - **Установка завершена**.

*Вопрос:*

> Как после запуска Ubuntu вернуться в Windows?

*Ответ:*

1. Если вы хотите чтоб на вашем ПК нормально работал Windows и Ubuntu. В случае установки с нуля (новый "чистый" ПК), рекомендую сначала устанавливать Windows. В случае установки Ubuntu быстрее Windows будут проблемы.
2. Если у вас уже установлена Windows, смело устанавливайте Ubuntu рядом как вторую ОС. Будте внимательны во время установки в моменте с *Разделами*
3. После того как Ubuntu будет установлена, вы можете менять системы через клавишу <kbd>F11</kbd>, нажимать ее необходимо во время загрузки, когда система начинает загружаться.
   Хотя еще могут быть разные моменты, но в целом принцип такой.

Comment: C запуском и установкой более менее понятно. Спасибо. Как вернуться назад из режима "Пощупать" и если на компе установлены две ОС?

Comment: Кстати на StackExchange есть сообщество посвещенное именно Ubuntu, но оно на английском. https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Как выйти из режима "Пощупать"? Тоже F11 после перезагрузки? Или просто сделать Shut down и извлечь USB?

Comment: А, да вы просто когда заходите в этот режим по факту у вас загружена Ubuntu, поюзайте ее, посмотрите, что к чему, выйти просто или нажать в верхнем правом углу выход или перезагрузка или же продолжаете дальнейшую установку.

Comment: У меня лэптоп с SSD. 256 GB. Сейчас занято 48 Gb. Если ставить рядом сколько памяти достаточно для работы с Ubuntu? Она мне нужен только для работы на С.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помогли.

Comment: Есть же главный источник https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1 и https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/ubuntu_install зачем занимайся копипастой?

Comment: @VladSpirin Добро, резон понятен. Откатить не могу пока голос.