# Какой debian поставить?

Tags: linux, windows, debian, windows-7, dual-boot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно поставить на компьютер Debian (как основную операционную систему) и Windows 7.

Вопрос: какой дистрибутив ставить?  Какова очередность установки, что должно первым ставиться, а что последним?

Железо: 12Гб ОЗУ, процессор intel core i7.

Comment: Гляньте по метке dual-boot, там много подобных вопросов есть с ответами

Comment: Последнюю стабильную

Comment: Тут есть ответы (все по аналогии): [Как запустить Ubuntu c загрузочного диска на USB / Как вернуться в Windows?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866754/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-ubuntu-c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-usb-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-windows/866765#866765)

Comment: Ох...., я ж написал, по аналогии. Ок, сначала ставите Windows, далее Debian. Порядок только такой, дабы избежать косяков далее. Версия: та которая на скрине 291 Мб

Comment: флешку лучше через [rufus](https://rufus.ie/en_IE.html) делать, так на всякий

Comment: @Vlad Spirin, ещё такой вопрос. Есть годная статья как правильно разбить место для Debian? Чтобы Debian не стерла винт весь. Windows 7 стоит.

Comment: Есть куча блогов. [Вот один из нормальных](http://compizomania.blogspot.com/), там должно быть. Сорри чуток занят на работе уже

Comment: Там с ссылке на вариант с убунтой, как раз про разделение дисков есть, глянь туда, как я и писал выше, по-аналогии

Comment: Proxmox + Winodws VM + любая другая VM по вкусу если для компании.  Если для себя - Debian Stretch + VM Windows. Цель ваша какая? Скрин ксатати не показывает полной версии текущей там 3 ДВД https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/  ставится 1й остальные по желанию (используются если нет Интернета).

Answer (score 0):

Официальные образы CD/DVD "стабильного" выпуска
https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/#stable

amd64 или i386 разрядность на ваше усмотрение