# GPT или MBR при двойной загрузке?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-7, dual-boot

Собираюсь установить Windows 7, и Ubuntu

Вопрос. Каких форматах должны быть разделы GPT или MBR?

И как установить так, чтобы не было такого после установки Windows 7 или Ubuntu? Т.е. при включении оставалась только одна ОС.
К примеру Ubuntu, т.е. чтобы можно было выбирать между Windows 7 и Ubuntu

Comment: что первым должно ставиться и последним? win или linux? разделы для windows и linux какие должны быть разделы GPT или MBR?

Comment: Есть инструкция: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/866765/262779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPT, он должен выбираться автоматически насколько помню. Установи ubuntu и при загрузке компьютера у тебя будет выбор в течении 15 секунд какую ОС загрузить вин7 или ubuntu.

Comment: что первым должно ставиться и последним? win или linux?

Comment: разделы GPT или MBR?

Comment: GPT, сначала win, потом ubuntu

Comment: спасибо тебе! за помощь!