# Перенос Windows 7 компакт-диска на флешку?

Tags: windows, windows-7, flash-память

Есть установочный компакт-диск Windows 7.
Как перенести файлы установки на флешку?

Comment: У вас он лицензионный? Имеется ввиду, зачем такой велосипед, когда можно скачать готовые образы и установить? Если вбить запрос в поисковик по вашему вопросу, ту куча ссылок с пошаговыми инструкциями. Какие сложности возникли?

Comment: В том-то и дело что не лицензия. sp1 хорошо крякнутая, качественная.

Comment: По не лицензиям я не в специалист и сомневаюсь, что на данном ресурсе вам будут помогать пиратское ПО множить. Поставьте ОС на ядре Linux, и не парьтесь, будет вам и лицензия, и поддержка, и проблемы уйдут...

Comment: Никогда не работал в linux, хотел но боялся, все твердят ос кривая, трудно в ней работать, косячит постоянно...

Comment: Те кто твердит, у них руки кривые. К примеру, Ubuntu, очень дружественная ОС, там у вас все будет установлено сразу, не надо офисы лепить, и куча софта, дрова ит.д.

Comment: Сами в linux работаете?

Comment: 1 win, 2 linux, 3 — ?

Comment: Какая из них ближе к сердцу?

Comment: Что посоветуете для именно web-разработки?

Comment: Можно было б конечно, но у меня ноутбучок asus k52 dr, 4гиг оперативки, трудно будет ему с двумя

Comment: не извиняйтесь, всё верно говорите, я это понимаю

Comment: Родная ос на ноутбуке была win 7, обновился до 10, после установки 10 всегда чёрный экран. переформатировал с mbr в gpt, чёрный экран ушёл, но тупить стало всё страшно

Comment: Уверенно работаю в git bush, всё,что мне нужно это локальный сервер и чтоб ровненько без сбоев всё работало. интуитивно мне по сердцу linux, потому что люблю всё самописное и руками-самодельное

Comment: Если задумаете Ubuntu ставить, вот я давал ответ как, пошагово: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/866765/262779

Comment: Любимый вами (и мной если чесно) git кстати Линус Торвальдс создал, он же и linux ядро написал

Comment: уже заглядывал к по вашей ссылке, единственно вопрос: перед установкой ubuntu придётся что-либо шаманить или само всё встанет?

Comment: Само все встанет если надо, или же можете разделы делить самостоятельно. Это уже не так сложно, принцип тот же что и при установке Виндовс, только названия отличаются. Главное флешку подготовить. Рекомендую использовать [rufus](https://rufus.ie/en_IE.html) для этого. Важный момент запомните пароль, сделайте его сложным, но запоминаемым для вас. По началу вам он будет нужен на постоянке, это определенная сложность в начале пользования (быстрее из-за непривычки), но зато повышенная безопасность. О...., и вы забудите как страшный сон про антивирусники

Comment: vlad спасибки, что потратил на меня время, попробую прямо сейчас и установить. К слову, Линуса Торвальдса знаю и очень уважаю этого человека, он реально хорош и заслуживает на мой взгляд уважения. Ещё раз спасибки большие за вразумления

Comment: Если поможет, обязательно :)

Comment: ок, я понял. Ну и ставить последнюю версию, да-не?

Comment: а почему, скажите пжл?

Comment: а,всё понял теперь

Comment: ок, понял. проголосовать не забуду

Comment: ок, спасибки большие!

Comment: Vlad, всё установилось без проблем, проще чем думал. Спасибки за подмогу, я благодарен.

Comment: Vlad, привет, начисто установил ubuntu по указанной выше ссылке (с оф.сайта). Сейчас буду ставить node.js & gulp и посмотрю, как будет работать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86921/discussion-between-vlad-spirin-and-dupre).

Answer (score 2):

Судя по каментам я видимо уже опоздал, но тем не менее:

[Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56485)

Прекрасно пишет как 7, так и 10. Но убивает всё что на флэшке было, аккуратнее.

Answer (score 1):

Может кому пригодится и такой проверенный рецепт - при наличии уже установленной Windows NT 6.x (Win7|8|8.1|10) с административными правами.

Запустить **diskpart** и начать исполнять следующие команды.

Вывести список всех подключенных дисков.

```
list disk
```

Найти номер нужного Вам флеш-диска из перечня (например 1).
Выбрать диск

```
select disk 1
```

Очистить флешку

```
clean
```

Создать основной раздел

```
create partition primary
```

Выбрать созданный раздел

```
select partition 1
```

Сделать активным созданный раздел

```
active
```

Форматировать раздел

```
format fs=FAT32 quick
```

либо

```
format fs=NTFS quick
```

смонтировать раздел

```
assign
```

Выйти из программы

```
exit
```

Скопировать целиком со структурой каталогов содержимое установочного компакт-диска на форматированную флешку.

P.S.
Полученная флешка грузится на большом множестве компьютеров. Замечено, что загрузчик, прописанный с помощью Windows 10, грузится даже на тех ПК, на которых не срабатывает загрузчик от Win7.

Comment: Это работает, но уже ubuntu