# Пытаюсь поставить Windows 10 и Unix-систему вместе на одном компьютере

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, linux-mint, dual-boot

Захотел испытать опыт работы с Unix-системами поставив Windows 10 и Ubuntu на одном ноуте, но не тут то было...
Отсек на жестком диске ноутбука 60Гб памяти, скачал на флешку Ubuntu последнюю версию с помощью ПО Unetbootin, отключил в BIOS `secure boot` и `fast boot`, запустился с флешки.
Во время установки Ubuntu попросили выбрать раскладку, что интересно - она не менялась, только английская. Забил на это и поехал дальше, в итоге увидел то что Ubuntu не видит никаких жесткого диска на моём ноуте, пустота в списке выбора (окошко "Тип установки"), снизу написано `/dev/sda`. Запустил Gparted, он видел только флешку с которой я запустился. Подумал на ПО Unetbootin.
Сделал флешку с помощью ПО Rufus, та же беда.
Попробовал менять флешки, результата ноль.
Подумал что установщик багованный, поставил версию Ubuntu 16-го года на флешку, то же самое, дисков не видит хоть убейся. Попробовал поставить Linux Mint, теперь раскладка менялась во время установки, но диск тоже не видит. При любых действиях с окошком "типа установки" следует вылет установщика, кроме нажатия кнопки выхода из установщика. Ноутбук Lenovo, стоит SSDшник один.

Comment: Заранее разделы подготовь с помощью Gparted, `/` в `ext4` и `/home` в том же `ext4` если ноутбук грузится в UEFI, можешь также сделать отдельный раздел и для него только уже в `fat32` (но можно воспользоваться и готовой efi Windows 10). `swap` - если ПК дохлый, если оператики достаточно, не нужно, но это на любителя. Я не делаю никогда, с момента как пробил барьер ОЗУ 16Гиг. Пройди по дубликату, там подробная пошаговая инструкция

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как запустить Ubuntu c загрузочного диска на USB / Как вернуться в Windows?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866754/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-ubuntu-c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-usb-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-windows)

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверить в bios какой режим SATA установлен. Должен быть AHCI
2. Разметить жесткий в винде предваратительно. Т.к. в линуксе этот процесс делается несколько иначе
3. Сразу изучить информацию на тему установки линукс и виндовс на один жесткий диск. Загрузчики двух систем будут конфликтовать. И после успешной установки по-умолчанию будет грузиться только одна система. У меня это была винда, т.к. я её ставил после линукса

Answer (score 0):

Если для начала Вы хотите только попробовать и испытать - совершенно не обязательно ставить отдельно. Если у Вас Windows 10 - используйте WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). Например - https://habr.com/ru/post/412633/ ссылок полно в сети.