# Установка Ubuntu 18.04 на второй диск

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, dual-boot

Стоит Win10, собрался ставить Ubuntu 18.04 на второй винт. На третьем файлопомойка.
Win10 на GPT, винт под Ubuntu, как я полагаю, тоже придется в GPT форматировать, а третий диск так и останется в MBR.
Вопросы: как размечать диск под убунту при установке? Нужен ли swap или 18.04 достаточно простого файла подкачки? Норм ли grub схватит винду и убунту? Как в общем сделать все красиво и без последствий?
Спасибо

Comment: Недавно ставил  убунту рядом с виндой. Не знаю что такое GPT и MBR. В моём случае единственно проблемой было то, что в BIOS стоял `Raid` вместо `AHCI` в разделе чего-то так, связанного с `SATA-контроллером`. Винду пришлось восстанавливать после переключения на `AHCI`, т.к. на `Raid` убунту не заводится. Grub так и не удалось запустить. В итоге по дефолту запускается винда, а убунту через меню `boot` надо вручную выбирать. В разметке диска ничего особенного не было. Судя по тому, что читал - файл подкачки - верное решение и никаких доп. разделов не нужно. Если у вас не `Raid` - то всё будет ОК.

Comment: Это только винде важно, gpt там или mbr (@ЮрийСПб, странно, что не знаешь). А линукс спокойно ставится на любую разметку и с неё работает. Если ты отдаёшь ей целиком физический диск, то пусть она его сама и размечает как ей вздумается. Чтобы подхватила винду, надо что-то внутри сделать - можешь поискать [по моим вопросам](//ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A178988+is%3Aq+%5Blinux%5D+%5Bwindows%5D), только у меня MBR. Но при желании можно и наоборот, в загрузчик винды прописать убунту, А можно и в оба друг друга, если диски разные. Ну и можно вообще в биосе выбирать, с чего грузиться.

Comment: @Qwertiy я правильно понимаю, что могу установить убунту на нужный мне винт, а загрузчик на винт с виндой? Просто сейчас попробовал поставить, вышло "не очень", биос по какой-то причине не показывает мой винт в списке очереди загрузки...

Comment: @АнатолийСоколов, можешь вообще все диски вынуть кроме нужного, на него поставить, а потом настроить диск с загрузчиком в биосе. Думаю, должно нормально получиться.

Comment: Вот вообще нивкакую... Пишет, что диск с только что установленной убунту - не загрузочный...

Comment: Всем спасибо, получилось. В биосе для uefi отдельно выставляется диск для загрузки, не в общем списке устройств

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/866754/262779

Comment: `swap` нужен если оперативки мало, если 8Gb и более то не нужен впринципе